# SELECT SQL, a number multiple of N

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a little help, i have the next situation:

```
SELECT MULTI, N FROM TABLE;
```

The result of the select:

```
MULTI    N
14       5
13       10
13       10
5        5
14       7
```

In that case I only want the results that match something like that:

`if (N % MULTI == 0)`, so `5` and `5` would be valid, and `7` and `14` too.

I don't know how I can do it in my `WHERE`. I hope you can help me out here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**MOD**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm) function as below

```
SELECT MULTI, N
FROM TAB
WHERE MOD(MULTI,N) = 0;
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8e1be/7/0)

Comment: It works thanks a lot. But im using alias and i can't put them in the WHERE, what i should do to put the alias?

Comment: @Rguy You can't use an alias in `WHERE` clause you need to use full expression insetad of alias.

Comment: The problem is that N is  something like that in my query:

CASE
  x + 10 = 40 THEN 5
  x + 20 = 30 THEN 7

And i don't know how to use it in the where

Comment: @Rguy Yes I understand you need to put it in to `where` insetad of alias, or maybe use it in subquery - then you can use alias name, If you put whole code it will be simpler to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use mod.

```
select MULTI,N,
CASE
   WHEN mod(N,MULTI)=0 THEN
    'VALID'
   ELSE
    'INVALID'
 END AS MOD_TES
 from TABLE
```

Comment: I tried but i can't use alias in the case... there is any method to use it?